# Is $x^6 + 1$ divisible by $x^2 + 1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I used polynomial long division and found that the remainder was $x + 1$.  So I concluded that $x^6 + 1$ is **not** divisble by $x^2 + 1$.  But this is not true since $x^6 + 1$ can be factored as a sum of cubes of $x^2$ and $1$.
What **can** we conclude if we use long division on two polynomials and get a non-zero remainder?

Comment: You made some mistake on the long division: the remainder must be $0$.

Comment: Hint: try substituting $y=x^2$ to see better what's going on.

Comment: @ Crostul.  Yes Thank you.  I made a mistake on long division.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes

Hint : $x^6+1=(x^2+1)(x^4-x^2+1)$

Answer (score 6):

$$x^6+1=(x^2+1)(x^4-x^2+1)$$

as à consequence of $a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$

Answer (score 5):

I would like to add a solution that does not explicitly factor $x^6+1$. Notice that $i, -i$ are roots of $x^6+1$ over $\mathbb{C}$. This means that $(x-i)(x+i) = x^2+1$ divides $x^6+1$ over the extension $\mathbb{C}$. Then $x^2+1$ divides $x^6+1$ even in $\mathbb{R}[x]$

Answer (score 1):

In general,

$$ a^3 +b^3 = (a+b)(a^2 - ab +b^2).$$

Let $a = x^2$ and $b=1$.

Comment: This looks a lot like the second-to-last sentence in the question: "But this is not true, since $x^6+1$ can be factored as a sum of cubes os $x^2$ and $1$."

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get your point.